# Consuming WebSphere service from WCF client: Unable to create AxisService from ServiceEndpointAddress

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf, websphere, wcf-client

I am consuming (or trying to consume) a WebSphere service from a WCF client (service reference + bindings generated through svcutil).

Connection seems to be established successfully but I am getting the following error:

```
CWWSS7200E: Unable to create AxisService from ServiceEndpointAddress [address]
```

Rings any bell?

I am guessing the request format is somehow being rejected by the service, I am sniffing it with fiddler and it looks fine overall (can post if ppl think it could help). Found [this article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK74377), but it doesn't seem to apply to my case.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of messing about with [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) I manage to understand this was related to the HttpHeader generated by the WCF binding:

**WCF generated HttpHeader** (response: Unable to create AxisService):

```
POST /MyWebServiceDomain/aWebService HTTP/1.1
```

**SoapUI HttpHeader** (works fine):

```
POST http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9080/MyWebServiceDomain/aWebService HTTP/1.1
```

Setting `hostNameComparisonMode="Exact"` on the WCF binding (I am using basicHttpBinding) did the trick, and the POST is being generated correctly, or at least in a way that the service likes.

Wasn't exactly an easy one - hope it helps someone else.

P.S. more about this on a related [blog post](http://dotnetbutchering.blogspot.com/2010/03/cwwss7200e-unable-to-create-axisservice.html).